# A simple question related to One-to-One function and linear operator

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, vector-spaces

I was stuck in one line derivation about the linear operator-related question:

> Suppose $T$ is linear operator maps from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$. and let $c>0$ be constant. If for all ${\bf x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $$c ||{\bf x}|| \le ||T {\bf x}|| \ \ \ \ (*)$$ 
>   then $T$ is one-to-one.

I know since $c>0$, $||T {\bf x}|| =0$ only happens when ${\bf x = 0}$. But I didn't get why we can infer that $T$ is one-to-one immediately?

The one-to-one definition says that: $f$ is one-to-one, 
If $x\neq y \Rightarrow f(x) \neq f(y)$. I didn't see how this definition link to the situation of $T$ clearly.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A linear operator is injective iff it's kernel is zero.  The direction you want follows from linearity:

If $T(x)=T(y)$ then $T(x-y)=0$ by linearity and so $x-y=0$.

Comment: Thank you @Seth, Do you mean applying the contraceptive statement of one-to-one function?

Comment: The definition of 1-1 that I am using is $T(x)=T(y)$ implies $x=y$.

Comment: I see! Thank you so much.